# Set bg image of li in dynamic menu using jQuery

Tags: jquery, image, dynamic, html-lists

Please bear with me, I've just started playing with js/jQuery.

I have a dynamically generated menu and wish to apply background images to each `li` based on the link text.
The text I can get with `.text`, and inserting the images is no problem either - I just need to find out to have the script stop and insert the corresponding image at each `li`.
I expected `.each` to do this but the following code runs through then applies the image for the last `li` to all of them.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#CategoryList li a').each(function() {               
            $('#CategoryList li').css('background','url(http://my_site.com/images/'+ (this).text +'.png) no-repeat');
        });
    });                            
</script>
```

Clearly I'm missing something basic (arrays perhaps?). All help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$(this).text()` instead of `(this).text`

```
 $('#CategoryList li').css('background','url(http://my_site.com/images/'+ $(this).text() +'.png) no-repeat');
```

As per my understanding you need

```
$(function () {
    $('#CategoryList li a').each(function () {
        $(this).closest('li').css('background', 'url(http://my_site.com/images/' + $(this).text() + '.png) no-repeat');
    });
});
```

Comment: spelling mistake with `closeset` it has to be `closest`

Comment: Thank you for the most complete answer - mark this as solved.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$(this).text()` This will return current `a` element text

Try this

```
 $('#CategoryList li').css('background','url(http://my_site.com/images/'+ $(this).text() +'.png) no-repeat');
```

Comment: On it's own this didn't solve the issue, but thank you for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

`(this).text` is not working please put `$(this).text()`

```
$(function() {
    $('#CategoryList li a').each(function() {               
        $('#CategoryList li').css('background','url(http://my_site.com/images/'+ $(this).text() +'.png) no-repeat');
    });
});
```

Comment: Combined with `.closest` the original `(this).text` does actually work, but obviously there is a reason to use the correct syntax so thank you for your answer.